# is it possible that MMU uses more than one paging logic?

Tags: operating-system, paging, mmu

is MMU's page table walking logic fixed?
or is it configurable by kernel?

I though MMU's logic is always fixed
but it seems to be the page table structure's
are different per OS...
or when I add more physical memory cards...

some advice would be nice
thank you in advance.

Comment: Depends on your platform. What are you working on?

Comment: I am studying about virtual address translation in depth. I saw platforms such as x86, x64, ARMv7, SPARC... I thought each CPU architecture has unique paging logic... now I am confused.

Comment: On which platform though? x86, ARM, etc...? Edit: Yes, each have different ways of walking the table.

Comment: I think there is more than one paging logic in my Intel core i3 x86 processor

Comment: it is using just one level of paging.(entry of cr3 -> page directory is physical PFN), however, on some other x86 cpu's, it uses two level paging(cr3->PGD->PTE->PFN)

Comment: I understand that 'different CPU' has 'different paging logic' however I am confused to that 'same CPU' can have 'different paging logic'

Comment: Depends on how you configure the MMU I guess. I had a quick look at the [x86 paging mechanism](http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging) and it seems you can have 4MB sections or further divide it into 4KB.

Comment: oh, I think the MMU's paging logic can be changed by page directory entry's flag! the flag is setted by OS, so I think this is the reason I am confused. thank you!